# How to use the new RVT->SVF Model Derivative parameter to generates additional content, including rooms and spaces?

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge

I’m following this https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/ tutorial in Forge and here is down my modelderivative.js file.
I’m trying to use the new RVT->SVF Model Derivative parameter to generates additional content, including rooms and spaces.
It says that I need to set the generateMasterViews parameter to true. And it requires the x-ads-force to be true also.
Any one know how to do it?????????

```
const express = require('express');
const {
    DerivativesApi,
    JobPayload,
    JobPayloadInput,
    JobPayloadOutput,
    JobSvfOutputPayload
} = require('forge-apis');
 
const { getClient, getInternalToken } = require('./common/oauth');
 
let router = express.Router();
 
// Middleware for obtaining a token for each request.
router.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = await getInternalToken();
    req.oauth_token = token;
    req.oauth_client = getClient();
    next();
});
 
// POST /api/forge/modelderivative/jobs - submits a new translation job for given object URN.
// Request body must be a valid JSON in the form of { "objectName": "<translated-object-urn>" }.
router.post('/jobs', async (req, res, next) => {
    let job = new JobPayload();
    job.input = new JobPayloadInput();
    job.input.urn = req.body.objectName;
    job.output = new JobPayloadOutput([
        new JobSvfOutputPayload()
    ]);
    job.output.formats[0].type = 'svf';
    job.output.formats[0].views = ['2d', '3d'];
    try {
        // Submit a translation job using [DerivativesApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#translate).
        await new DerivativesApi().translate(job, {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
        res.status(200).end();
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
 
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on how you framed the question, I assume you have seen this article already:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces

This has a sample request body that shows how e.g. the "**output**" section should look like:

```
"output": {
  "formats": [{
    "type": "svf",
    "views": [
      "2d",
      "3d"
    ],
    "advanced": {
      "generateMasterViews": true
    }
  }]
}
```

From this you can see that "**advanced**" would need to be added at the same level as "**type**", so you would need to add this to your code:

```
job.output.formats[0].advanced = {generateMasterViews: true};
```

If you hover above the **translate**() function, then an info popup should appear - something like this:
​
[image]

From that you can see, that you can add { **xAdsForce**: **true** } to the input options.
This will add the **x-ads-force** header to the request.
So you would call **translate**() like this

```
await new DerivativesApi().translate(job, {xAdsForce: true}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the details could be found at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces, hope it helps.